MCP2200 communication with HID under LINUX
I would like to use the following product as an input module(know whether a signal (12~24V DC) is present or not via the GPIO pins).
https://denkovi.com/usb-8-opto-isolated-digital-inputs-module
the protocol
https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/SupportingCollateral/93066A.pdf
I would like to program it in C or C++ (hidapi or external libraries are not wanted).
an excerpt from the terminal

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04d8:00df  
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass          239 
  bDeviceSubClass         2 
  bDeviceProtocol         1 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x04d8 
  idProduct          0x00df 
  bcdDevice            1.01
  iManufacturer           1 Microchip Technology Inc.
  iProduct                2 MCP2200 USB Serial Port Emulator
  iSerial                 3 0010891880
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x006b
    bNumInterfaces          3
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Association:
      bLength                 8
      bDescriptorType        11
      bFirstInterface         0
      bInterfaceCount         2
      bFunctionClass          2 
      bFunctionSubClass       2 
      bFunctionProtocol       1 
      iFunction               0 
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         2 
      bInterfaceSubClass      2 
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 
      iInterface              0 
      CDC Header:
        bcdCDC               1.10
      CDC ACM:
        bmCapabilities       0x06
          sends break
          line coding and serial state
      CDC Union:
        bMasterInterface        0
        bSlaveInterface         1 
      CDC Call Management:
        bmCapabilities       0x00
        bDataInterface          1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               2
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass        10 
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0020  1x 32 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         3 
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      29
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0010  1x 16 bytes
        bInterval               1
can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)

I have tried the simple example, which unfortunately returns incorrect values.
the correct values should be:
idVendor           0x04d8
idProduct          0x00df

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/hiddev.h>
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void){
    int fd=-1;
    fd= open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR);
    if(fd<0){
        fprintf(stderr,"Can't open device: %s\n",temppath);
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("DEVICE opened\n");
    }

    struct hiddev_devinfo dinfo;
    ioctl(fd, HIDIOCGDEVINFO, &dinfo);
    close(fd);
    printf("VendorID           0x%X\n", dinfo.vendor);  // it returns 0x400
    printf("ProductID          0x%X\n", dinfo.product); // it returns 0x0
}


You should check the return value from ioctl(). Maybe it is failing.

MCP2200 is a composite USB device that will appear both a a serial and an HID device. /dev/ttyACM0 is the device path for the serial device. You need to use the path for the HID device.

yes you are right, ioctl() fails >> ioctl HIDIOCGDEVINFO failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
/dev/bus/usb/001/001 - Linux_4.14.79-ge669d52447_musb-hcd_MUSB_HDRC_host_driver_musb-hdrc.0
/dev/bus/usb/001/002 - Microchip_Technology_Inc._MCP2200_USB_Serial_Port_Emulator_0010891880
/dev/ttyACM0 - Microchip_Technology_Inc._MCP2200_USB_Serial_Port_Emulator_0010891880
/dev/bus/usb/002/001 - Linux_4.14.79-ge669d52447_musb-hcd_MUSB_HDRC_host_driver_musb-hdrc.1
I have tried all 4 paths >> same failure >> ioctl HIDIOCGDEVINFO failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device –

I see no justification for "embedded" or "microchip" tags in this question.  Clarify or remove the irrelevant tags.  The fact that the device is from the company "Microchip" does not make the tag relevant - they make many devices, and this is not a programmable device even.
